# How did Dante know that the Elric brothers were going to bring back their mother Trisha?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-2003

In the FMA Wikia it says this...

> In the first anime series, the remains of the failed human
>   transmutation that was Trisha takes on a larger role. After the
>   brothers rush away from the scene looking for help, the deformed,
>   living mass that was created manages to crawl away. Patiently waiting
>   not far from the house was Dante, who fed it the Red Stones necessary
>   to give it a human form.

Which leaves the impression that Dante knew that they would perform human transmutation on their deceased mother. Isn't it a bit strange that Dante is so conveniently close to the house when the incident happens? It seems to me that she knew this would happen.

So how did Dante know that the Elric brothers were going to bring back their mother Trisha? I also can't remember when this happened in the series. Please list the episode in your answer if possible.

Comment: Ed seems to figure out who she is when he meets her in episode 41 towards the end, but I have a feeling the bit where they show her eating up the stones is later.

Comment: The episode where we see her eating the stones is in 47, in the second half. She also seems to make some comment about how she expected them to attempt human transmutation.

Comment: It seems as though someone is -1 all my FMA Questions. :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite possibly one of the Homunculi was keeping an eye on Izumi at the time being an alchemist who could have wanted the Philosopher's Stone and saw the Elricks learning Alchemy from her and reported back to Dante, given how much they look like Hohenheim of Light Dante may have followed them back in hopes that she might see Hohenheim.

Another reason could be the exact same as Mustang having received a letter from the Elricks asking about Hohenheim and came to look for Hohenheim, or suspected that because Ed and Al was Hohenheim's sons they might also be foolish enough to do Human Transmutation as she and Hohenheim did with their Son.

This is really just speculation though, the start of the 2003 anime plays out much like brotherhood yet they deviate because the Manga was on going and Dante is a 2003 only character, as for which episode we see Dante meet Sloth for the first time i don't remember but if i was to guess it might be around when Hohenheim faced Dante after seeing Ed and Al and first encounter Sloth, it would make sense for it to appear here as Dante would be showing off Sloth to Hohenheim.

Comment: I'm just going to wait before accepting your answer just in case there are others. : )

Comment: @MiharuDante that's fine, mine was just speculation for the most part, someone might have a more concrete answer